# Binary XML file line #318: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have problem and display error: **Binary XML file line #318: Error inflating class fragment**
here is my some code but I can't post all code because stack overflow not allow to post code more then description.

her is my extend :

```
extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback

SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

XML

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: kh.com.iknow.iknow, PID: 6764
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kh.com.iknow.iknow/kh.com.iknow.iknow.BusinessDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kh.com.iknow.iknow.BusinessDetail.onCreate(BusinessDetail.java:48)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: @KamranAhmed : Process: kh.com.iknow.iknow, PID: 17406
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kh.com.iknow.iknow/kh.com.iknow.iknow.BusinessDetail}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #318: Error inflating class fragme

Comment: Adding the whole of logcat in your question would be useful. You issue is hidden in your logcat.

Comment: in your Business‌​Detail activity,which xml file is binding of that activity?please check line 318 in that xml file which is binding in your Business‌​Detail activity.

Comment: @dipali: in line 318 is <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="200dp"
              />

Comment: You can probably remove manifest file content from the question and replace it with full the logs.

Comment: @KamranAhmed : please check Update Logcate

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, you are trying to use an object that points to null. You can find the problem at **line number 48** of your `BusinessDetail.java` file as indicated here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at kh.com.iknow.iknow.BusinessDetail.onCreate(BusinessDetail.java:48)
```

If you are not able to debug the issue, you may post the code that is there at  line 48 and perhaps a few more around it.